# How to configure maxArchiveDays on NLog FileTarget using config variable

Tags: xml, nlog

i have int variable in NLog.config
`<variable name="logLifetime2"  value="5"/>`
but when i use it in `maxArchiveDays="${logLifetime2}"` i have error. maxArchiveDays see my variable as string.

```
<variable name="logLifetime2"  value="5"/>
<targets>
     <target name="Global" xsi:type="File"
              fileName="Logs/GlobalLog.txt"
              archiveNumbering="Date"
              enableArchiveFileCompression="true"
              archiveFileName="Archive/IPSlog.{#}.zip"
              archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
              maxArchiveDays="${logLifetime2}"
              archiveEvery="Day" />
</targets>
```

How to create in NLog.Config int variable?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the entire content of your NLog.config ? What version of NLog are you using? When using NLog-config-variables inside NLog.config, then they act as verbatim-copy and will just work.

Comment: `<variable name="logLifetime2"  value="5"/>

  
  
  <targets>
    <target name="Global" xsi:type="File" fileName="Logs/GlobalLog.txt"  archiveNumbering="Date" enableArchiveFileCompression="true" archiveFileName="Archive/IPSlog.{#}.zip" archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" 
     maxArchiveDays="${logLifetime2}"
    archiveEvery="Day" />` i use last nlog nugget package. i cant send all Nlog.config because there is char limit

Comment: When others are posting comments about missing details in your question. Then it is better that you just edit your question, and include the missing details in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using this config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog throwConfigExceptions="true" internalLogFile="${basedir}/Logs/nlog-internal.txt" internalLogLevel="Debug" >

  <variable name="logLifetime2"  value="5"/>

  <targets>
    <target name="Global" type="File"
       fileName="Logs/GlobalLog.txt"
       archiveNumbering="Date"
       enableArchiveFileCompression="true"
       archiveFileName="Archive/IPSlog.{#}.zip"
       archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
       maxArchiveDays="${logLifetime2}"
       archiveEvery="Day" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="Global" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then my nlog-internal.txt contains this:

```
2020-11-12 16:01:58.1235 Debug Setting 'NLog.Targets.FileTarget.maxArchiveDays' to '5'
```

So it works on my machine. Make sure to use a version of NLog where maxArchiveDays is supported ([Introduced with NLog 4.7](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target))

But I guess you have to live with any errors coming from XML-Schema (XSD)-validation, since NLog-Config-Variables are very special.

Comment: i have problem with intellisense for Nlog.config. this example really works

Comment: @ИванОнищенко Ahh so your issue was with XML-schema-validation. My example does not include XSD-validation, so that is why no errors. Remember to update your NLog.xsd when updating NLog. See also: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema